Calculated, non-nullable, non-persisted nvarchar in SQL
Consider the following schema:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [Id]                BIGINT              NOT NULL    IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [NameGiven]         NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL,
    [NameMiddle]        NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL    CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_User_NameMiddle] DEFAULT (''),
    [NameFamily]        NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL,
    [Email]             NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL,
    [NameTest]          AS ' ', -- Shows as NON NULL.
    [NameFull]          AS  COALESCE(REPLACE(CONCAT(TRIM([NameGiven]), ' ', TRIM([NameMiddle]), ' ', TRIM([NameFamily])),'  ',' '), ''),
    [NameFullOutlook]   AS  COALESCE(REPLACE(CONCAT(TRIM([NameGiven]), ' ', TRIM([NameMiddle]), ' ', TRIM([NameFamily]), ' ', '(', [Email],')'), '  ', ' '), ''),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

The statement is legal and creates the desired table, but out of the three calculated columns, only [NameTest] shows up as NOT NULL when I query the schema or view it in the SSMS designer.
Note that the calculated fields refer only to other columns that are NVARCHAR and NOT NULL. I want the [NameFull] and [NameFullOutlook] columns to show up as non-null as well. These columns should not be persisted.
So I suspect that one or more of the functions being used (COALESCE, CONCAT, REPLACE, TRIM) are causing this. Is there an elegant way to fix this without making the formula too convoluted to read?
In case anyone wants to know, I am writing a small expression evaluator for end-users, hence want the syntax to be succint.
UPDATE: I even tried adding  + ' ' to the end of the formulas, and it still shows up as null.


Does handling the possibility of NULLS in the formula help isnull(x,' ')  Also CONCAT_WS may help with the tidying

@Nathan_Sav: Thanks, that worked! Actually, CONCAT_WS does help with tidying up, too. You should post your comment as an answer.

Even though Nathan posted his comment as an answer, it should not have been downvoted. It solved the problem and he was first to respond. Sorry mate.

Well you also did not marked the answer from Nathan as accepted answer. I commented on his answer with tips on how to not get downvoted, but I see he now removed his answer

@GuidoG: I agree with you. The answer was already deleted by the time I got to it.

You can go for ISNULL instead of COALESCE, as they are treated differently for Nullability, as explained in the below MSDN article.

The NULLability of the result expression is different for ISNULL and
COALESCE. The ISNULL return value is always considered NOT NULLable
(assuming the return value is a non-nullable one). By
contrast,COALESCE with non-null parameters is considered to be NULL.
So the expressions ISNULL(NULL, 1) and COALESCE(NULL, 1), although
equal, have different nullability values. These values make a
difference if you're using these expressions in computed columns,
creating key constraints or making the return value of a scalar UDF
deterministic so that it can be indexed

You can go for ISNULL as given below:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [Id]                BIGINT              NOT NULL    IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [NameGiven]         NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL,
    [NameMiddle]        NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL    CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_User_NameMiddle] DEFAULT (''),
    [NameFamily]        NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL,
    [Email]             NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL,
    [NameTest]          AS ' ', -- Shows as NON NULL.
    [NameFull]          AS  ISNULL(REPLACE(CONCAT(TRIM([NameGiven]), ' ', TRIM([NameMiddle]), ' ', TRIM([NameFamily])),'  ',' '), ''),
    [NameFullOutlook]   AS  ISNULL(REPLACE(CONCAT(TRIM([NameGiven]), ' ', TRIM([NameMiddle]), ' ', TRIM([NameFamily]), ' ', '(', [Email],')'), '  ', ' '), ''),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


The problem is your use of COALESCE, which is defined as NULLable. There is, however, no need for it, in truth; you can make the whole expression more succinct with CONCAT_WS:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] --USER is a reserved keyword, and is a poor choice of name for an object. Use a better, more descriptive, name
(
    [Id]                bigint              NOT NULL    IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [NameGiven]         nvarchar (256)      NOT NULL,
    [NameMiddle]        nvarchar (256)      NOT NULL    CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_User_NameMiddle] DEFAULT (''),
    [NameFamily]        nvarchar (256)      NOT NULL,
    [Email]             nvarchar (256)      NOT NULL,
    [NameTest]          AS ' ', -- Shows as NON NULL.
    [NameFull]          AS  CONCAT_WS(' ',TRIM([NameGiven]),TRIM([NameMiddle]), TRIM([NameFamily])),
    [NameFullOutlook]   AS  CONCAT_WS(' ',TRIM([NameGiven]), TRIM([NameMiddle]), TRIM([NameFamily]), '(', [Email],')'),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

If you can't use CONCAT_WS,you can spoof it with CONCAT and STUFF instead, which is more succinct, but you'll still need a ISNULL, to force NULLability:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [Id]                BIGINT              NOT NULL    IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [NameGiven]         NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL,
    [NameMiddle]        NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL    CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_User_NameMiddle] DEFAULT (''),
    [NameFamily]        NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL,
    [Email]             NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL,
    [NameTest]          AS ' ', -- Shows as NON NULL.
    [NameFull]          AS  ISNULL(STUFF(CONCAT(' ' + TRIM([NameGiven]), ' '+ TRIM([NameMiddle]), ' ' + TRIM([NameFamily])), 1, 1, ''),''),
    [NameFullOutlook]   AS  ISNULL(STUFF(CONCAT(' ' + TRIM([NameGiven]), ' '+ TRIM([NameMiddle]), ' ' + TRIM([NameFamily]), ' ' + '(', [Email],')'), 1, 1, ''),''),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

db<>fiddle

Don't wanna be that guy but CONCAT_WS was introduced in sql server 2017

I could have sworn it was 2012, @siggemannen .

At least it doesn't work on my sql server 2016

Yeah, it's just me misremembering when different features came out, @siggemannen . It was CONCAT that was added in 2012.

Funnily enough, i was lamenting lack of concat_ws yesterday when build a \path\subpath from nullable columns :) The STUFF trick is a good alternative

This problem is primarily caused by the fact that you are using replace, which can return null. You also use coalesce which can itself return null if all of its operands are null. If you replace coalesce with isnull the problem goes away.

No need to use ISNULL. In fact the problem is REPLACE because you can replace a value by a non value....
SELECT REPLACE('toto', 'to', NULL) => NULL

To simplify and present your data much more clearly you can write :
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [Id]                BIGINT              NOT NULL    IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [NameGiven]         NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL,
    [NameMiddle]        NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL    CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_User_NameMiddle] DEFAULT (''),
    [NameFamily]        NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL,
    [Email]             NVARCHAR (256)      NOT NULL,
    [NameTest]          AS ' ', -- Shows as NON NULL.
    [NameFull]          AS  CONCAT(TRIM([NameGiven]) + ' ', TRIM([NameMiddle]) + ' ', TRIM([NameFamily])),
    [NameFullOutlook]   AS  CONCAT(TRIM([NameGiven]) + ' ', TRIM([NameMiddle]) + ' ', TRIM([NameFamily]) + ' ', '(' + [Email] +')'),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

Your concatenation could conduct to bizarre spaces if one of the columns changes to NULL instead of NOT NULL
